# Display text below other text also need space between text and dropdown symbol

Tags: html, css

we have Brand and model dropdown boxes looking like  [this link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/) as below image

[image]

I want to make like this :

[image]

**css**

```
#brand_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}



#model_select
{
color: #000000; 
text-transform: capitalize;
font-size:17px;
font-weight:bold;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

**html**

```
<?php

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';

<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>'

?>
```

we want to Display **My model** below **My Brand** also want to give space between **My Brand** text and dropdown symbol.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Comment: Can we have some code to base on ? The CSS you gave us looks like only a part of your code, and maybe some html if your divs are inside a container or something.

Comment: @Relisora please check updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add static width to dropdowns, for example `width: 150px;`

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Mindaugas/17eLs0oz/

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea wghat font we need to use to look like in 2nd image ?

Comment: Looks like "Open Sans", 18px, Bold https://www.google.com/fonts#QuickUsePlace:quickUse/Family:Open+Sans

Answer (score 1):

you can put your select elements inside a div element for them to be as you want.

for the space between the boxes you can use padding.

for the space between the text and the dropdown symbol you can use width.

you may see an example here:
https://embed.plnkr.co/NypAPGHZmrBjh88nZfnW/

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to achieve the attached image. Not very neat but I hope you get the point.

```
select{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: 2px solid #bbb;
            background: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            background: url(downarrow.png) no-repeat right white;
            z-index: 100;
        }
```

[My test form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9gzY.png)